# How to install openpyxl in PyCharm as I am getting this error message

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, openpyxl

I am trying to install `openpyxl` in PyCharm using command `pip install openpyxl` in terminal and I am getting the following error :

```py
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certifica
te in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/openpyxl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certifica
te in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/openpyxl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certifica
te in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/openpyxl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certifica
te in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/openpyxl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certifica
te in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/openpyxl/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/openpyxl/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/openpyxl/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVeri
ficationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for openpyxl
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationEr
ror(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

**1.** Open **PyCharm**.

**2.** go to `File -> settings -> Project:test(test means your project name) -> select project interpretor -> click add button`

[image]

**3.** after clicking add button and **search** `cryptography` then **install** it.

[image]

finally, run the program.